# How to set line-height for GWT RichTextArea

Tags: gwt

I want to set line-height for `RichTextArea` component in `GWT`. How could I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added initialization handler to my custom `RichTextArea` and external css `richtextarea.css`:

```
 addInitializeHandler(new InitializeHandler() {
        public void onInitialize(InitializeEvent ie) {
            Document document = IFrameElement.as(getElement()).getContentDocument(); 
            BodyElement body = document.getBody(); 
            HeadElement head = HeadElement.as(Element.as(body.getPreviousSibling())); 
            LinkElement styleLink = document.createLinkElement(); 
            styleLink.setType("text/css"); 
            styleLink.setRel("stylesheet"); 
            styleLink.setHref("richtextarea.css"); 
            head.appendChild(styleLink);
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following class to your application css

```
.gwt-RichTextArea
{
line-height: 5px;
}
```

No need to add this class explicitly to your richtextarea as the GWT component listens to this css Class by default.